# Using ajax and jquery to hit a jersey url and pass it data

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jersey

Homepage.jsp:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var startZArray = new Array();

function add()
{
  var startZ = $('#startZ').val();
  startZArray.push(startZ);
}

function submitP()
{
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url:"/horn/rest/main/schedule",
  data: startZArray,
  success:function()
  {alert('worked');}
  });
}
</script>
```

Homepage.java

```
  @POST
  @Path("/schedule")
  public void tigerMessage(
      @Context final HttpServletResponse response,
      @Context final HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception
  {
    String[] myParams = request.getParameterValues("startZArray");
    System.out.println(myParams);
  }
```

Unfortunately myParams prints out null.  I know that inside add startZArray is getting populated.  But I'm not sure if data: startZArray is the proper way to pass it.  Also I know that the Jersey url is being hit because I do see null printed out.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Edit:

When I do:

```
[~] curl -i -X POST -d "{\"startZArray\":\"testMessage\"}" http://localhost:8080/horn/rest/main/schedule
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Date: Wed, 24 Apr 2013 20:15:18 GMT
```

I still get null so I think something is wrong in my java code?

Edit2:

I updated for debugging the submitP() method:

```
function submitP()
    {
        var myarray = ['Element 1', 'Element 2', 'Element 3'] ;
        var dataobject = {
            postvar: myarray
        } ;

        $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url:"/horn/rest/main/schedule",
                    data: dataobject,
                    success:function()
                    {
                        alert('worked');
                     }
                });
    }
```

When I run the code in firebug the output post looks something like this:

```
Paramaters:
postvar[]   Element 1
postvar[]   Element 2
postvar[]   Element 3

Source:
postvar%5B%5D=Element+1&postvar%5B%5D=Element+2&postvar%5B%5D=Element+3
```

The post had a status of 204 and said "No Content" for some reason.

I've also tried putting `postvar[]` and just plain `postvar` into the getParameterValues method with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your submitP() in Edit2

Try this in jersey

```
  @POST
  @Path("/schedule")
  public String tigerMessage(
      @FormParam("postvar[]") List<String> vars) throws Exception
  {
    System.out.println(vars)
    return ""
  }
```

Update:

Another approach

```
  @POST
  @Path("/schedule")
  public String tigerMessage(
      Form form) throws Exception
  {
    System.out.println(form);
    // Then get parameters from form
    return ""
  }
```

Comment: This worked but I would really like to do it without @FormParam, do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I am not sure it is because of Jersey or the web server. But in my memory the requests were also without information of parameters when using Jersey and Grizzly. You can try another approach in my update. Or if you can pass the parameters through JSON, then you can use a Map or your own object as an argument in your resource.

Answer (score 1):

you are not sending your data with a parameter so you can't get that with `startZArray`

```
request.getParameterValues("startZArray");
```

Try this -

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url:"/horn/rest/main/schedule",
  data:{ "startZArray" : startZArray },
  success:function()
  {alert('worked');}
});
```

Comment: no need for `$(this)`.. .. I have update's my answer.. try that.

Comment: Thank you for the updated answer but it still didn't work, I got null again.

Comment: Hmm.. can you try this and see what param. you are getting - `request.getParameterNames();`

Comment: Yea I tried it with that too, still null.  I believe its in my content body because when I do request.getContentLength() its the size of the stuff I pass in to the POST.  But I don't know how to get the information out of the Content body.

Comment: Ok..so have you tried wrapping your script within `$(document).ready()` ??

Comment: I tried that but had no luck... I just updated the question with what I know after some debugging.  Thank you for your help any more ideas?